# wampserver green icon but unable to connect in php

Tags: php, wamp

I have been using wamp 2.2 on windows 7 since 3 months. Suddenly, it stopped working. I tried re-installing. I dont have skype, no iis or any server, i have also tried changing port 80 in http.config file. I m using mozilla, it shows error: unable to connect. Not even xampp is working. Help me out, please.

Comment: what err is showing when you trying to start wamp?

Comment: check the `error.log` file of apache.

Comment: This might be a silly comment but you are not running WAMPServer and XAMPP at the same time are you, because that will definitely get everything confused.

Comment: Browser shows: unable to connect error,
And i tried to run xampp once only when wamp failed, i have already uninstalled it.

Comment: Have you installed something recently that also comes with a instance of Apache and/or MySQL. Two versions of MySQL will cause you untold hassle unless you know what you are doing.

Comment: After failure of wamp, i tried for xampp and uninstalled it later but right now, there is no such clashing server in my pc.

Comment: Is'nt there anybody around the globe who could help me out.